# PHP - как парсить не правильный JSON

Tags: php, json, парсер

Получаю со страницы json действием json_encode(array_merge($_GET, $_COOKIE)), но не корректный, его нельзя просто прогнать через функцию json_decode. Вот сам json:

```
{
    "_ga":"***",
    "_fbp":"***",
    "_ym_uid":"***",
    "_ym_d":"***",
    "roistat_is_need_listen_requests":"*",
    "___dc":"***",
    "_fbc":"***",
    "_gac_UA-***":"***",
    "__cfduid":"***",
    "_gid":"***", //примерно отсюда начинается часть куки
    "roistat_visit":"***",
    "roistat_marker":":utm:youtube_referral_name:u:of:u:video",
    "roistat_marker_old":":utm:youtube_referral_name:u:of:u:video",
    "leadhunter_expire":"1",
    "_ym_isad":"2",
    "roistat_call_tracking":"1",
    "roistat_emailtracking_email":"null",
    "roistat_emailtracking_tracking_email":"null",
    "roistat_emailtracking_emails":"null",
    "roistat_leadHunterScriptsShownCount":"{"undefined":1}", // вот тут начинаются проблемы
    "roistat_leadHunterCaught":"1",
    "rngst2":"{"utmz":{"utm_source":"youtube","utm_medium":"referral","utm_campaign":"(not set)","utm_content":"name_of_video","utm_term":"(none)"}}"
}
```

Из-за этого не могу спарсить данные. Есть какой-то способ это исправить? Возможно функция которая такие ошибки распознает. Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: это не похоже на результат работы json_encode. Покажите код, которым вы получаете такую строку

Comment: @AterLux json_encode(array_merge($_GET, $_COOKIE))

Comment: Такая конструкция (без параметров) не выдаёт такой json. По умолчанию он выдаётся в одну строку, а кавычка внутри значений предшествуют слэши. То есть ошибка где-то между json_encode и тем, как вы этот текст получаете

Comment: @AterLux Перенос строки я сделал для удобства, конечно же это в одну строку. Меня и удивило то, что закодировав через _encode не могу раскодировать _decode

Comment: 1) сделайте `var_export(array_merge($_GET, $_COOKIE));` 2) сделайте `var_dump(json_decode( json_encode(array_merge($_GET, $_COOKIE))));`